# Spring Security what is the difference between Authorization Manager and AccessDecisionManager?

Tags: spring-security

Spring Security what is the difference between Authorization Manager and AccessDecisionManager, and how do they interact with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthorizationManager`, from [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#_the_authorizationmanager):

> AuthorizationManager supersedes both AccessDecisionManager and AccessDecisionVoter.
> Applications that customize an AccessDecisionManager or AccessDecisionVoter are encouraged to change to using AuthorizationManager.
> AuthorizationManagers are called by the AuthorizationFilter and are responsible for making final access control decisions.

The **deprecated** `AccessDecisionManager`, from [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/architecture.html#authz-access-decision-manager):

> The AccessDecisionManager is called by the AbstractSecurityInterceptor and is responsible for making final access control decisions.

In summary, the `AuthorizationManager` is a new API that supersedes the `AccessDecisionManager`. If you are using `authorizeHttpRequests` instead of `authorizeRequest`, you are already using the `AuthorizationManager` API.